# Wrapping a material-ui component in a library to re-use it in multiple other projects breaks styles

Tags: material-ui

The title already says it and we do have a working example. However, the library we have built does have it's own customTheme and uses styles to such an extent that we cannot just copy them to the projects importing the library.

Right now we do get the following error on multiple developer machines:

> It looks like there are several instances of `@material-ui/styles` initialized in this application.
>   This may cause theme propagation issues, broken class names, specificity issues, and makes your application bigger without a good reason.
>
> See https://material-ui.com/r/styles-instance-warning for more info.

Is there a best practice for creating Material-UI components in a library which can then be reimported into other projects with its styles and everything of course then inheriting colours etc. from the project the library is imported to.

Comment: Do you have an answer for this? I face this same issue

Comment: Yes and no ;) ... one of my colleagues of course now has solved the problem. But there is still quite a lot of styling going on inside of the component. We now resorted to adding class attributes to all our elements such that we can override look and feel in the including application via CSS.